# Get first day of 2019 in week 1 java

Tags: java, calendar

I try to get the first day of the *year=2019* in *week=1*, which is 01.01.2019, but what i get is 31.12.2018. How come and how to solve this?
Here is my code:

```
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);               
    cal = this.resetCalendarTime(cal);
    cal.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, Integer.parseInt(*week*));
    cal.set(Calendar.YEAR, *year*);

    cal.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    LocalDateTime dptbg = cal.toInstant().atZone("Europe/Berlin").toLocalDateTime();
```

Comment: You are mixing good, bad and even unused things in your code, what you want to achieve exactly? if you want to get `01.01.2019` then why not just `LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 1)`

Comment: You are using `LocalDateTime` which mean you are using *java.time* library so please don't use legacy (Calendar) in your code

Comment: @YCF_L They want '2016-01-04' for the year 2016, because week 1 in 2016 started on jan 4th; in other words, LocalDate.of(year, 1, 1) isn't what they are looking for... _IF_ that date is actually in week 52/53 of the previous year, which it sometimes is, but they want jan 1st and not e.g. 2018-12-31 even though 2018-12-31 is day 1 of week 1 of 2019. Why? Beats me, but it's more complicated than 'just jan 1 st'. See my answer.

Comment: Yes @rzwitserloot this is correct, I was in my way to answer `LocalDate.of(2019, 1, 1)
        .with(WeekFields.ISO.weekOfWeekBasedYear(), week)
        .with(WeekFields.ISO.dayOfWeek(), day);`, but your answer is better ;)

Answer (score 3):

The Calendar API is broken and crap. It's been replaced (... because it is broken and crappy) with the new `java.time` API, which you should use. The Calendar API lies (An instance of `j.u.Calendar` isn't a calendar at all. It's some weird amalgamation of solarflares time and human appointment time, the API isn't very java like at all (`.set(someIntegerConstant, whatnow)`?) - in case you need reasons beyond 'it was replaced').

Because the rules about 'when does the week start' are so bizarre, the new API encapsulates all these rules into an instance of the class `WeekFields`. You can create one either based on 'minimalDaysInFirstWeek' + 'firstDayOfWeek', or you provide a locale and java will figure it out based on that. Seems like you wanna go by locale, so let's do that!

```
public LocalDate getFirstDayInYearInFirstWeek(int year, Locale locale) {
  WeekFields wf = WeekFields.of(locale);
  LocalDate firstDayOfYear = LocalDate.of(year, 1, 1);
  LocalDate firstDayOfFirstWeek = firstDayOfYear
    .with(wf.weekOfYear(), 1)
    .with(wf.dayOfWeek(), 1);

  return firstDayOfFirstWeek.isBefore(firstDayOfYear) ?
     firstDayOfYear : firstDayOfFirstWeek;
}
```

let's try it:

```
System.out.println(getFirstDayInYearInFirstWeek(2019, Locale.GERMANY));
> 2019-01-01
System.out.println(getFirstDayInYearInFirstWeek(2016, Locale.GERMANY));
> 2016-01-04
```

success!